# Using msvcrt.getch and printing output

Tags: python-3.x

Can someone explain to me why this simple code will not print the variable 'k'?

```
def simple_code():
    k = msvcrt.getch()
        if k == chr(120):
            print("foo", k)
        else:
            sys.exit()
```

Comment: From the documentation of msvcrt it seems that getch with return the next character that the user presses. That character is then compared with chr(120) which is a lowercase x. Once the user presses x the code should then print the tuple ("foo", "x"). https://docs.python.org/2/library/msvcrt.html

Comment: Right. It's weird. I press x or any other key and it exits. I've tried it within the terminal in PyCharm and in a command prompt.

Comment: When I run it seems to work fine PS C:\Users\KarlGraham\Documents\messing around  > python .\msvcrt.py 
  ('foo', 'x'). What do you see when you print k before the if statement?

Comment: Sorry i was reading the docs for python 2. It seems that in python 3.x the function returns a byte string. You may have to decode the k varible first e.g. k.decode() == char(120). https://docs.python.org/3/library/msvcrt.html

Comment: It works, but with a 'b' before it. What would that stand for?

(venv) F:\PycharmProjects\PokerControl>pokermanager.py --client ACR
foo b'x'

Comment: @KarlGraham if we print before the if statement, I get b'x'

Comment: Well, regardless, it actually recognizes the key and then minimizes all windows which is what I wanted to begin with. I was just testing the functionality to begin with and that's why I was getting confused. I'm still curious why there's a 'b' before x... weird to me. But I'm new to Python, so I defer to someone else.